# Update handler variables in netty server

Tags: server, netty

I'm new to netty framework and I try to write netty server.

I have Handler in which constructor I pass a configuration (some parameters which may change while the server is running). The configuration must be updated (let's say every 10 minutes). What is the best way to do it?

I can change it in `public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch);` method but that seems like a bad idea to me.

Are there any built-in mechanisms to solve my problem?